# Non-parametric test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I was given the following exercise:

The Results obtained by 10 students in a test are the following:

72 95 79 83 93 80 91 74 70 86

Test the hypothesis that the mean score is 75.Use two test:one parametric and another non-parametric.

My doubt is for the parametric test, should I make a t-student test? Because I don't have a big sample to use the normal distribution...

Comment: You may find my answer here: [Problem understanding what type of test to use and how to proceed](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27588//27597#27597) to be helpful in thinking about this.

Comment: Given that this is a homework/textbook exercise, one can neglect the fact that the data are discrete. In order to check the normallity assumption you can use the Shapiro test. In R: `x = c(72, 95, 79, 83, 93, 80, 91, 74, 70, 86); shapiro.test(x);`. The p-value is $0.65$, then it is reasonable to use a t-test. Final hint: `t.test(x, mu=75, alternative="two.sided")`.

Comment: What is the level of your class? What tests (both parametric and nonparametric) have you learned? My guess is that your teacher wants to to have an "a ha!" moment when you compare the results of the 2 tests. This could come easily from comparing the results of a t-test and a sign test (or other tests that you have covered), the comparison may then lead you to investigate why they are the same or different (looking at if the usual conditions for the tests hold). You will probably need to find out from your teacher if I have guessed correctly and how strict they are on what tests you use. Note a

Comment: yes, i was thinking about t-test and sign test, but isn't sign test about median?

Comment: @Procrastinator, why is there any need to use distribution testing *for normality* in order to justify using the t-test? That is not one of the usual assumptions for applying a t-test.  (Approximate normality of the distribution of the *sample mean* is the usual assumption.)

Comment: @whuber Because the sample size is small. I see your point of using the CLT but appealing to it with $n=10$ may be arguable as well.

Comment: @Proc I don't believe I mentioned the CLT at all--it doesn't apply. The t-test will be reasonably accurate (and powerful) when the underlying data are not strongly skewed and have no really extreme outliers, *whether or not* the sample appears to come from a normal distribution.

Comment: @whuber My logic is the *opposite*. If the assumption of normallity is reasonable, then the assumptions of the t-test hold.

Comment: @Proc Thanks; that's a helpful clarification. (By referring to "the normality assumption" your comment is written as if--or at least is easily read as if--the logic were different from that.)

Comment: @Procrastinator The test for normality only has enough power to be useful in circumstances where the sample is large enough that the central limit theorem can be relied upon. With a small sample the test will fail to convincingly show non-normality no matter how extreme the departure. I find the notion of deciding whether the particular type of measurement can be plausibly normal is much more useful.

Comment: @MichaelLew Good point. I do not know how powerful this test is for this sample size. Although the empirical decision about normallity is equally arguable. Fortunately, the t-test is robust, as whuber described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Student's t-test is specifically designed to deal with small samples. If your textbook doesn't make that clear, then try another textbook ;-).

For that test to be appropriate, the data need to be plausibly approximately normally distributed. Student's t-test is commonly regarded as being fairly 'robust' in that moderate departures from normality do not muck it up too much. In this specific case you should consider the fact that the distribution of marks may be bounded (e.g. 0% and 100%?) and so cannot be normal. However, if the scores are well away from the bounds then it might be close enough, at least by being roughly symmetrical. (You can explore the approximate distribution by bootstrapping, if you are interested.)